# How to format exported data from mongodb

Tags: python, json, mongodb

I have a `document` in a collection of my `mongodb` database whose format is like this:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "18ad45c2c081aa"
    },
    "some_date": "Tue Jan 25 01:41:35 +0000 2018",
    "id": 1077378793470193664
}
```

But when I *export* my collection using `mongoexport` the downloaded json file has the document in this format:

```
{  
   "_id":{  
      "$oid":"18ad45c2c081aa"
   },
   "some_date":"Tue Jan 25 01:41:35 +0000 2018",
   "id":{  
      "$numberLong":"1077378793470193664"
   }
}
```

This is because

> [To preserve type information, mongoexport and mongoimport uses the
>   strict mode representation for certain types.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/index.html)

But I need my data to be exactly the same as the former format. I couldn't find the solution in the mongodb documentation for [mongoexport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/index.html) or [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/)

How do I get the exported data in the same format as in the database?